# PHP multidimetional array null check

Tags: object, multidimensional-array, php

i have the following value passed to me via a webservice

```
print_r($result);

stdClass Object (
    [array] => Array ( [0] => [1] => ) 
)
```

i break it down as follows

```
$result = $array->return;
foreach ($result as $val2)
{
    $temp = $result[$i]->array[0];
    $temp .= " - ". $result[$i]->array[1];
}
```

I want to check if the array is empty (as it is above). but i cant access the array via the

```
$result[$i]->array[0];
```

as i get Fatal error:

> Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

What is the best way to check it?

Answer (score 1):

stdClass is not an array, it is an object. But you access it like an array:

```
$result[$i]
       ^^^^
```

Shouldn't it be something like (without the `foreach`):

```
$array = $result->array;
$temp  = vsprintf('%s - %s', $array);
```

UPDATE:

So to test if it is empty, you can just use

```
if (empty($result->array[0]))
   ....
```

Comment: stdClass Object ( [array] => Array ( [0] => [1] => ) )  is the print_r of $result